# PUT requests not working on Server side (node js)

Tags: node.js, rest, zendesk, zendesk-api

I am trying to make a PUT request in Node JS to update the "value" field. Here is my code:

```
var identityJson = {};
identityJson.identity = {};
identityJson.identity.value = "+61111111111";
var url = "https://[Zendeskdomain].zendesk.com/api/v2/users/[user ID]/identities/[Identity ID].json";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 )
        {
            console.log(this.status)
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    }

request.open('PUT', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
request.send(JSON.stringify(identityJson));
```

This script returns 200 as the status and prints the identity as it was before. In this case, the value is still "+37011111111"

```
200
{"identity":{"url":"https://[Zendeskdomain].zendesk.com/api/v2/users/[user ID]/identities/[Identity ID].json","id":[Identity ID],"user_id":[user ID],"type":"phone_number","value":"+37011111111","verified":true,"primary":true,"created_at":"2018-09-07T12:24:02Z","updated_at":"2018-09-07T12:24:02Z"}}
```

If I send the same request on client side (putting the script on a simple webpage), the value does change so it seems that the information entered is correctly formatted.

Anybody has had similar issues (in Zendesk or not) while submitting a PUT request from Node JS and can point me in the right direction?

**Note:** [Zendeskdomain], [user ID] & [Identity ID] are irrelevant for this so I removed them, however they are correctly entered in the script.

Thanks!

Comment: if you are already on the server, the protocol (https) for a PUT req is unnecessary. have you thought about simply making a function call without the protcol wrapper?

Comment: Thanks @RobertRowntree. I'm in my own server (basically calling this from Terminal) and making these calls to a third party Server (Zendesk) so I don't think calling a function is an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in server side, don't use XMLHttpRequest, it's a javascript client side function...

Use a package like request : https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Then just do :

```
request({
  method: "PUT",
  uri: "http://sdfsfdsdf",
  json: body
 }, function(err, response, body){
    ....
});
```